# Global low level keyboard hook freezing in c# .net 3.5

Tags: c#, winapi

i have a frustrating problem with registering global hook.
I am using this class in my windows application:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

class InterceptKeys
{
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static void Hook()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Test");
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

Here is Program.cs

```
namespace TestHooks
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            InterceptKeys.Hook();
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
        }

    }
}
```

Everything works (MessageBox pops up) but windows freezes for a moment and beeper beeps. The problem doesn't occur on Windows 7 just on Vista. Any suggestions please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use MessageBox in your code.  It blocks execution, the keyboard goes dead.  Use Console.WriteLine() for example, output goes to the Visual Studio Output window.

Beware that this code won't work anymore on .NET 4.0, GetModuleHandle() will return NULL.

Comment: thank you so much. I am now using BeginInvoke now to trigger events so that i can handle Pressed Keys...