# Program is unresponsive for a couple of seconds

Tags: c#

I found a way to capture the `Print Screen` button in C#. When pressing `Alt + Print Screen` a simple messagebox pops up saying the keys have been pressed. **But** it's unresponsive for a couple of seconds right after. I have no idea why this is happening.

Here's the code I use:

```
static class Program
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The main entry point for the application.
    /// </summary>
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);
        Application.Run(new Form1());
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);  
    }

    /****************************************/
    private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
    //private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;  
    private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
    private const int VK_F1 = 0x70;
    private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {

        if (nCode >= 0)
        {
            Keys number = (Keys)Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
            if (number == Keys.PrintScreen)
            {
                if ((wParam == (IntPtr)260 && Keys.Alt == Control.ModifierKeys && number == Keys.PrintScreen))
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("You pressed alt+ print screen");
                }
            }

        }
        return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam);

    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName); 
}
```

Does anyone have a clue why it's hanging after the messagebox?

Comment: keep a break point here `return CallNextHookEx(IntPtr.Zero, nCode, wParam, lParam);` and see whats happens..does it wait or not?

Comment: It waits, yes. It waits for a couple of seconds and then jumps to Visual Studio..

Comment: Sounds similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2999013/global-low-level-keyboard-hook-freezing-in-c-sharp-net-3-5

Comment: try this [lobal-keyboard-hook-slowing-down-computer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6891570/global-keyboard-hook-slowing-down-computer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows cannot dispatch the next keyboard message until the hook callback finished executing.  Clearly you do *not* want to use MessageBox.Show(), that blocks the callback.  Windows puts up with that for several seconds before it declares your code broken and disables the hook.

Use Debug.Print() instead.

Comment: I need to show another form, which also seems to block it. What would be the best way? Start a new thread which will show the form?

Comment: Calling a form's Show() method should not be a problem.  ShowDialog() *is* a problem, that's a blocking call.  Use the BeginInvoke() method to run the code later, don't use threads.